When an existing question raises for you an additional question about the law, please ask that as a new Q&A
Sometimes when reading a question, you will realize there is a gap in your own legal knowledge.
Instead of using a comment to ask that the question author explain the law to you, you should ask your question as a new question on the site. This approach is better for the site.
Asking a fresh question is preferable for various reasons:

if you don't know the point of law, many others will also not know, and by writing a proper question, this will help preserve your question and any answers you receive;
it will grow this site's Q&A collection;
actual questions will get many more views than comments, and are more likely to attract better, more complete, better cited, and more diverse answers than should be provided in a comment thread;
the author of the original question themself might not know the law;
it is unreasonable to have the question author explain to you a point of law that, if they understood it, might contain the answer to the the very question they're asking.

Of course, if you are suggesting an improvement or clarification to the question, a comment or edit is appropriate. But in that case: actually suggest what kind of clarifying edit is needed. A question about what the law is is not a suggestion for improvement.

I thought Meta was still of the Q&A format, or is it appropriate to post opinions here?  Or should I ask that as a new question?!  ;)
